# UNIX/ copy directory to new directory

Tags: unix, directory, cp

I need to copy a directory and its content to a NEW directory.

Using: `cp -r dir1/dir2 dir1/dir3` 
where `dir3` is going to be created anew, it just copies the file(s) I have within `dir2`... It's like it copies `dir2` naming it `dir3`.
Is there any way to copy `dir2` *into* `dir3`?

I need to do it with a single command.

Comment: "Using a single command with options, copy the `play` directory in the `practice1` directory to a new directory in the `practice1` directory called `appointments`."

Answer (score 1):

It's not really possible to do it in 1 command with `cp`. What you want is for *dir3* to already exist when you do your copy. I'm not sure if there's a real reason why you have to do it in 1 command or not. You can certainly do it in one *line*.

`mkdir dir/dir3;cp -r dir1/dir2 dir1/dir3`

Comment: In the comment I added i pasted what's asked on the oracle practice manual... :)
Maybe I just misinterpreted it

Comment: Based on that, I'm thinking your original cp command was correct then.